# Prevent subpages from redirecting to the root URI

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having a minor but annoying issue with a site running WordPress 3.1.4 Multisite.

Navigating to the URI of a subpage without the "http://www" such as "abetterworldbydesign.com/2011-conference/" results in a redirect to the root "http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com".

The intent is for "abetterworldbydesign.com/2011-conference/" to redirect to "http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/2011-conference/".

.htaccess file below (it's [specific stuff for WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite)).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abetterworldbydesign.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

at the very top, just after `RewriteEngine On`.